# Error when compiling c# project with reference to external DLL

Tags: dll

I'm trying to compile [the following c# code](https://offsec.provadys.com/docs/pulse-secure-arbitrary-file-write-eop/PulseLogPrivesc.cs) which relies on the external DLL [which source code is located there](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools/tree/master/NtApiDotNet)

So at first I compile the DLL project source code through:

```
dotnet build NtApiDotNet\NtApiDotNet.Core.csproj -c Release
```

I obtain the NtApiDotNet.dll, so everything good until there.

But, then I'm trying to compile the c# source code referencing the previous DLL with the following command line:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /unsafe /platform:anycpu /r:NtApiDotNet.dll /out:poc.exe .\PulseLogPrivesc.cs
```

I obtain the following error log entries:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /unsafe /platform:anycpu /r:NtApiDotNet.dll /out:poc.exe .\PulseLogPrivesc.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.2556.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

PulseLogPrivesc.cs(72,17): error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is
        not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
NtApiDotNet.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
PulseLogPrivesc.cs(72,17): error CS0012: The type 'System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that
        is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
NtApiDotNet.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
PulseLogPrivesc.cs(72,17): error CS0012: The type 'System.IConvertible' is defined in an assembly that        is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
NtApiDotNet.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
PulseLogPrivesc.cs(72,17): error CS0012: The type 'System.ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is        not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
NtApiDotNet.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
NtApiDotNet.dll: error CS0455: Type parameter 'A' inherits conflicting constraints 'System.ValueType'
        and 'System.IConvertible'
PulseLogPrivesc.cs(169,21): error CS0012: The type 'System.Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not        referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
NtApiDotNet.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
PulseLogPrivesc.cs(174,13): error CS0012: The type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeBuffer' is
        defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
        'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
NtApiDotNet.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
PulseLogPrivesc.cs(186,21): error CS1061: 'NtApiDotNet.NtMappedSection' does not contain a definition
        for 'ReadArray' and no extension method 'ReadArray' accepting a first argument of type
        'NtApiDotNet.NtMappedSection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly        reference?)
PulseLogPrivesc.cs(191,21): error CS1061: 'NtApiDotNet.NtMappedSection' does not contain a definition
        for 'WriteArray' and no extension method 'WriteArray' accepting a first argument of type
        'NtApiDotNet.NtMappedSection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly        reference?)
```

I tried to locate the external DLL on different folders: current directory, csc.exe directory.
Do you know what is the problem?

I also tried to compile the DLL from Visual Studio but I'm getting
[the following error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqmlH.png)

Comment: Don't mix .NETCore with .NETFramework.  Let Visual Studio help you get this right.

Comment: I edited with the error message I get with Visual Studio, I do not really know how to handle this...

Comment: Your VS version is probably too old to know what to do with .NETCore projects.  Consider updating to VS2019, the Community edition is a free download.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately, VS2019 is compiling my DLL, but the csc.exe command line is still failing...